# ADP API Client Secret for OAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, node-modules, adp-api

Our company currently uses the ADP Run app and we are working with the ADP API for an in-house web app (NodeJS) that will get employee clock / time data. The API is pretty straight forward but I am unable to authenticate to get a bearer token because we can find a "client secret" anywhere for our account and I have been unsuccessful in getting this information from any contacts at ADP. We have the CSR certs and the Client ID but not a client secret and we can't connect to the API without it. Could someone who has experience in working with ADP API please point me in the right direction on how to obtain this for an account?

Answer (score 1):

A brief skim suggests to me that that API uses the `authorizaton_code` OAuth2 flow, which does not use a client secret.

`password` and `client_credentials` flows both require secret, but not `authorization_code`.

Answer (score 0):

Your representative should provide you with your ClientID and Secret.

I am trying to call on ADP API as well. I can generate an accesstoken in Node referencing their documentation, https://developers.adp.com/articles/guides/build-dataConn-app-w-dev-lib-Nodejs, but I don't know how to grab it and use it to access other ADP endpoints.

[Grabbing the accessToken within ADP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928603/grabbing-the-accesstoken-within-adp-api)